# Logout user with services not working

Tags: service, drupal-7

I am working on a mobile app which I will be deploying using Phonegap.

Now I am able to login using Drupal 7 services and I am also getting the session name and session id. But I am not able to Logout the user. When even I am doing that.. I see this issue on my chrome console: 406 (Not Acceptable:)

I tried sending headers as "Cookie" then "sessionname=sessionid" format.. but that didn't work. Can someone please suggest a way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the CSRF token from `YOUR_SITE/services/session/token`, and then add it to the header in the same way you added the `Cookie`, something like

```
'X-CSRF-Token: ' + $token
```

And make sure it's `PUT`, there is a nice example here:

http://pastebin.com/N35SN7Xj

The relevant section looks like this:

```js
$.ajax({
   url: "http://your_url/endpoint/user/logout.json",
   type: 'post',
   dataType: 'json',
       beforeSend: function (request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
    },
   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert('Failed to logout');
     alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
     alert(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
     alert(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
   },
   success: function (data) {
     alert("You have been logged out.");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: drupal_instance + api_endpoint + 'user/logout',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': user.token
    }
})
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('Success');
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('Error');
});
```